# Numba vectorize a function if only one of its inputs could have different dimensions

Tags: python, numba, array-broadcasting

Given an array of points with shape (2, n) the function returns the n interpolated values.
The function should also work if points is a 1-d array (2,). I think numba vectorize could be used to solve this elegantly but I havent gotten it to work.

```
from numba import njit, vectorize, float64

@njit
def bilinear_interpolation(points, matrix, axis_0_start, axis_0_step, axis_1_start, axis_1_step):
    res = np.empty(points.shape[1])
    for i in prange(points.shape[1]):
        point0_loc = (points[0, i] - axis_0_start) / axis_0_step
        point1_loc = (points[1, i] - axis_1_start) / axis_1_step

        idx_0l = math.floor(point0_loc)
        idx_0h = idx_0l + 1
        idx_1l = math.floor(point1_loc)
        idx_1h = idx_1l + 1

        mat_hl = matrix[idx_0h, idx_1l]
        mat_ll = matrix[idx_0l, idx_1l]
        mat_hh = matrix[idx_0h, idx_1h]
        mat_lh = matrix[idx_0l, idx_1h]
        
        res[i] =   (mat_ll * (idx_0h - point0_loc) * (idx_1h - point1_loc) +
                    mat_hl * (point0_loc - idx_0l) * (idx_1h - point1_loc) +
                    mat_lh * (idx_0h - point0_loc) * (point1_loc - idx_1l) +
                    mat_hh * (point0_loc - idx_0l) * (point1_loc - idx_1l))
    return res
```

I have tried:

```
from numba import njit, vectorize, float64
@vectorize([float64(float64, float64, float64[:, :], float64, float64, float64, float64)])
def bilinear_interpolation(point0, point1, matrix, axis_0_start, axis_0_step, axis_1_start, axis_1_step):
    point0_loc = (point0 - axis_0_start) / axis_0_step
    point1_loc = (point1 - axis_1_start) / axis_1_step

    idx_0l = math.floor(point0_loc)
    idx_0h = idx_0l + 1
    idx_1l = math.floor(point1_loc)
    idx_1h = idx_1l + 1

    mat_hl = matrix[idx_0h, idx_1l]
    mat_ll = matrix[idx_0l, idx_1l]
    mat_hh = matrix[idx_0h, idx_1h]
    mat_lh = matrix[idx_0l, idx_1h]
    
    res =   (mat_ll * (idx_0h - point0_loc) * (idx_1h - point1_loc) +
                mat_hl * (point0_loc - idx_0l) * (idx_1h - point1_loc) +
                mat_lh * (idx_0h - point0_loc) * (point1_loc - idx_1l) +
                mat_hh * (point0_loc - idx_0l) * (point1_loc - idx_1l))
    return res
```

Comment: [`@guvectorize`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) is certainly the tool you are searching for. If it is not powerful enough then I do not think you can use Numba vectorization (`vectorize` is more restricted).

Comment: Note this operation cannot efficiently benefit from SIMD instructions on most machines, especially old one. It requires gather instructions which tends to be inefficiently implemented on all processor I am aware of. On top of that Numba also need to support wraparound which is AFAIK hard to vectorize. The computation of `res` can be speed up by SIMD instruction though. Still, I expect the gather and the memory accesses to be a bottleneck. Thus, while you could get a performance improvement, it should be relatively small.